# "No Excel data found in file." when reading input from .xlsx and writing the output to .xml file (i/p file to be in .xlsx format) + perl

Tags: html, xml, perl

My excel file has three columns. Xml format can be of any type. Just I need to extract the contents. Any help is appreciated.

```
Input(as in .xlsx):

Date    Name    Subject
07/22/2020  AAA Severity: 1 - Critical has been assigned
07/23/2020  BBB Severity: 2 - Medium has been assigned
```

My Code:

```
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use XML::Writer ();
use XML::Writer::String ();
use IO::File;
use File::Find;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse("D:/input.xlsx");

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
my $xml_doc = XML::Writer::String->new();
my $xml_file = new IO::File("D:/output.xml");
my $xml_doc_writer = new XML::Writer(OUTPUT =>  $xml_file);             


for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    my %header = ();
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            if ($row == 0) {
                $header{$col} = $cell->unformatted();
            } else {
                $xml_doc_writer->dataElement($header{$col},$cell->unformatted());
            }
        }
    }

}
$xml_doc_writer->endTag();
$xml_doc_writer->end(); 
$xml_file->close();
```

Output:

```
No Excel data found in file.
```

Can any one tell me, why its showing this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel in Perl, but need help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846582/using-spreadsheetparseexcel-in-perl-but-need-help). In short: the problem is likely in the input file, like wrong format of the file. Further help requires the actual input file you are using.

Comment: Please try `Spreadsheet::XLSX` instead of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`. If that does not work please upload the input file somewhere where we can download it and try to reproduce.

Comment: parse method calls _get_content() which Get the Excel BIFF (Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Binary File Format (.xls). Also known as BIFF8.) content from the file or filehandle. if data length is zero, function will return (ErrorNoExcelData,   'No Excel data found in file',    # 2) so use Spreadsheet::XLSX module as suggested by Hakon Hagland